# How to see which functions in an xcode program are being called

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I'm trying to understand an Objective-C program that I downloaded. It has a lot of functions and I'm interested in what is being called, and the order that the functions are being called in.

I can accomplish this by putting a `printf` statement at the beginning of each function, but there are a lot of them. Is there another way?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint at the start of the program, then stepping/debugging through it?

Comment: Oh, OK, that kind of works. But it's also slow. Are there any shortcut keys or anything to make this easier?

Answer (score 3):

You can use GDB and go step by step with breakpoints

> http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/